# Rao-Blackwell Problem

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, rao-blackwell

Let $X_1, .. X_n$ be iid Bernoulli($\theta$).

I want to estimate $\lambda = \theta(1-\theta)$ using $\delta$ (unbiased estimator for $\lambda$) where

$\begin{cases} 
      \delta = 1 & X_1 =1 \text{ and } X_2 = 0 \\
      \delta = 0 & \text{else} \\
   \end{cases} $

**Problem: Rao-Blackwellize $\lambda$ to get a better estimator**

**My Attempt**: I use the fact that a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ in a  Bernoulli($\theta$) variable is $\sum x_i$.  Then, $\bar{x}$ would *also* be a sufficient statistic.

So we would have: $E[\delta \mid \bar{x}] = \bar{x}(1-\bar{x})$.

Comment: Yes $\bar x$ is sufficient for $\theta$ but your $\delta$ is not unbiased for $\theta(1-\theta)$.

Comment: Yeah it is. $E[\delta] = P(X_1 = 1 , X_2 = 0) = \theta(1-\theta)$. EDIT: Apologies, I wrote the distribution incorrectly!

Comment: Your current answer for the conditional mean has to be scaled for it to be an unbiased estimator.

Comment: What would I need to scale it by?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3086919/321264.

Comment: Still unclear what I'd need to scale my conditional mean

Comment: Perhaps you could show how you obtain your answer. Since your estimator is not unbiased, by finding its mean you can get the appropriate scaling.

Comment: I am unsure how to do that -- as I thought that the expectation was xbar(1-xbar)

Comment: There are answers here and in my linked post that should clear things up.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track but the claim about $E[\delta | \overline{x}]$ is not true in general.

Rewrite $\delta = X_1(1 - X_2)$. In order to find the conditional expectation, let's first find the conditional probability. Note that since $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim Bernoulli(\theta)$ iid, we have that the sum of any $k$ of the random variables, denote $S_k$, will be a $Binomial(k, \theta)$ random variable. Let $S = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, then $S$ is sufficient for $\theta$ and also $\lambda = \theta(1-\theta)$.

Consider $P(\delta = 1 | S_n = s) = \frac{P(\delta = 1, \: S_n = s)}{P(S_n = s)}$, we then have that since $S_n$ is binomial, that 
\begin{equation*}
P(S_n = s) = \binom{n}{s}\theta^s(1 - \theta)^{n-s}
\end{equation*}
and 
\begin{align*}
P(\delta = 1, \: S_n = s) & = P(S_n = s | X_1 = 1, X_2 = 0)P(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 0) \\
 & = P(\sum_{i=3}^n X_i = s - X_1 - X_2 | X_1 = 1, X_2 = 0)P(X_1 = 1)P(X_2 = 0) \\
 & = P(S_{n-2} = s - 1)\theta(1 - \theta) \\
 & = \binom{n-2}{s-1}\theta^{s-1}(1 - \theta)^{n-2 - (s-1)}\theta(1 - \theta)  \\
 & = \frac{s(n-s)}{n(n-1)}\binom{n}{s}\theta^s(1 - \theta)^{n-s}.
\end{align*}

This means that we have $P(\delta = 1 | S_n = s) = \frac{s(n-s)}{n(n-1)}$. Now, since
\begin{equation*}
E[\delta | S_n = s] = 1 \cdot P(\delta = 1 | S_n = s) + 0 \cdot P(\delta = 0 | S_n = s) = \frac{s(n-s)}{n(n-1)}
\end{equation*}
we are done, with the Rao-Blackwell estimator being given by
\begin{equation*}
\delta_{RB} = \frac{s(n-s)}{n(n-1)}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. But  why is $[\delta \mid \bar{x}]$  not $(\bar{x})(1-\bar{x})$

Comment: Let's look at the explicit expression $E[\delta | \overline{x}]$, we have that
\begin{equation*}
E[\delta | \overline{x}] = \sum_{\delta=0, 1} \delta \cdot P(\delta | \overline{x}) = 0 \cdot P(\delta | \overline{x}) + 1 \cdot P(\delta | \overline{x}) = P(\delta | \overline{x}).
\end{equation*}

Comment: From here if you follow my derivation you see that it's not the same. I think you make the mistake of thinking that $E[\delta | \overline{x}] = E[X_1 | \overline{x}](1 - E[X_2 | \overline{x}])$ and plugging in $\overline{x}$, but that is not true.